# How to define OpenJDK 8 in CentOS based Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile, java

Assuming that there is a CentOS Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos
```

What is the right way of adding OpenJDK 8 for it ?

I have tried to use similar approach as for Fedora https://github.com/projectatomic/docker-fedora-images/blob/master/java-openjdk-8/Dockerfile

But when I run the image java version is *"1.7.0_111"*, even though it is expected to be JDK 8:

```
docker run -i -t <image> /bin/bash

[user@2fcc1e47c3cd projects]$ java -version

java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.7.2.el7_2-x86_64 u111-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)
```

There are many sources which describe Oracle JDK installations, but I was not able to find any relevant instructions for OpenJDK

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems to be as easy as this:

```
FROM centos

RUN yum install -y \
       java-1.8.0-openjdk \
       java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

ENV JAVA_HOME /etc/alternatives/jre
.
.
```

Comment: I'm actually getting `bash: java: command not found` after I build the container and run `docker run -it {image_id} /bin/bash` followed by `java -v`.

Answer (score 7):

When JDK for development is installed, then JAVA_HOME should point to JDK instead of JRE.

```
RUN yum install -y \
   java-1.8.0-openjdk \
   java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/
```