# Installing java 8 in centos 7 dockerfile

Tags: docker, java-8, centos

I just looked at this question: [How to define OpenJDK 8 in CentOS based Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636338/how-to-define-openjdk-8-in-centos-based-dockerfile).

I tried the suggested answers, but I'm not getting the expected results. Here are the contents of my DockerFile

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum install -y \
       java-1.8.0-openjdk \
       java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

ENV JAVA_HOME /etc/alternatives/jre
RUN yum install maven
RUN yum install curl 
RUN yum install -y unzip
```

I am building the image via: `docker build -t container_image:latest -f DockerFile.build .`
Then when I run `docker run -it {image_id} /bin/bash`  and perform `java --version` I get `bash: java: command not found`. Can someone help me see what I am doing wrong here?

Also, when I try to install the jdk from within the container via `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk` I get the following

```
java --version
Unrecognized option: --version
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This fixed it

```
FROM centos

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y remove java
RUN yum install -y \
       java-1.8.0-openjdk \
       java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

RUN yum install -y maven
RUN yum install -y curl 
RUN yum install -y unzip
```

Answer (score 0):

a slightly edited version from @Evan's answer above for those who are getting `Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist`

```
RUN cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
RUN sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y remove java
RUN yum install -y \
       java-1.8.0-openjdk \
       java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

RUN yum install -y maven
RUN yum install -y curl
RUN yum install -y unzip
```